# Updating in pickle using binary file

Tags: python-3.x, list, pickle

I am writing a code that makes a contact book using pickle module and binary modes. I am confused over updating part. Below is my code for that:

```
def update():
f=open("data.txt",'rb+')
record=pickle.load(f)
user=str(input("What do you want to update?(N for name and C for contact number)"))
if user=="N":
    value=str(input("Enter the old name:"))
    new_value=str(input("Enter new name:"))
    for g in record:
        if g[0]==value:
            g[0]=str(new_value)
elif user=="C":
    value1=int(input("Enter the old contact number:"))
    new_value1=int(input("Enter new contact number:"))
    for p in record:
        if p[1]==str(value1):
            p[1]=str(new_value1)
else:
    print("Contact doesnot exist!")
record=pickle.dump(record, f)
f.close()
update()
```

I dont know why this function does not updates my original file. It doesnot throws any error either which can give me some hints.  Is there any other pickle sub-function that can be used to update the exisiting file because I googled and didn't find one.
Can you point out my error? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know the file is not being updated? For instance, does the file size change after you run this code?

Comment: Open for reading, read it, close it.  Similar for writing

Comment: @Alex When I run the whole code, this function also executes and I input the data but it shows my original data not the updated one.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen When I open it in write mode, it throws error.

Comment: Did you close it from reading first?

Comment: Yes, I closed it in other function before this one. And I have a separate function for reading, after update function, in which I reopen this file in read mode.